# $f(x) = 1 - |1 - 2x|$, $a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$, prove convergence of subsequences

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Let $f(x) = 1 - |1 - 2x|$, $a_1 = a$, $a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$. Prove there exists $a \in [0, 1]$ such that for every $x \in [0, 1]$ there exists a subsequence of $a_n$ convergent to $x$. I've tried to analyze the graph of this function, but couldn't spot anything useful.

Answer (score 3):

First to all we express a generic $x\in ]0, 1]$ as a $2$-base decimal sequence
$$
x=0.x_1x_2x_3\dotsc x_n\dotsc=\sum^{+\infty}_{i=1}\frac{x_i}{2^i}
$$
where $x_i\in\{0, 1\}$. Now remember that $1=0.11111\dotsb$ then
$$
1-x=\sum^{+\infty}_{i=1}\frac{1-x_i}{2^i}
$$

Application $f$ as said Hagen von Eitzen does on $x$ this transformation:

- If $x_1=0$ then simply shift to left $x$;
- If $x=1$ then change all $0$ in the "decimal part" with $1$ and vice versa, then shifts it to left.

Let $A=\{x\in ]0, 1[: x $ has a **finite** representation as decimal in base $2\}$ clearly $A$ is dense in $[0, 1]$ so we need to show that for every element of $A$ exists a subsequence of $a_n$ that converges to it. Let $l:\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathbb N$ (without $0$) such that
$$
2^{l(n)}\leq n < 2^{l(n)+1}
$$
(the $2$-length of $n$) and let
$$
j:n\in\mathbb N\rightarrow\{0, 1\}
$$
defined in the right manner so that if
$$
a=\mathtt{'0.'}+n+j(n)+\mathtt{'001'}
$$
then
$$
f^{l(2n+1)}(a)=\mathtt{'0.001'}
$$
or in other words the value of next numbers won't be changed after $f$ has passed $2n+j(n)$

> Example: if $n=\mathtt{'101'}$ and $l(n)=3$ then $j(n)=\mathtt{'0'}$ because
>   $$
> \mathtt{'0.101,0,001'}\\
> f\rightarrow\mathtt{'0.0101110'}\\
> \mathtt{'0.101110'}\\
> f\rightarrow\mathtt{'0.010001'}\\
> \mathtt{'0.10001'}\\
> f\rightarrow\mathtt{'0.01110'}\\
> \mathtt{'0.1110'}\\
> f\rightarrow\mathtt{'0.0001'}\\
> \mathtt{'0.001'}\\
> $$

Observe that
$$
l\left(2n+j(n)\right)=l(n)+1
$$

Observe that any element of $A$ is in the form
$$
\frac{1}{2^{u-1}}\frac{n}{2^{l(n)}}
$$
where $n, u\in\mathbb N$, we also define $L(n)=\sum^{n}_{i=1}[i+l(i)+1]$ and $L(0)=0$

We built $a$ as limit of a sequence $b_n$ created from $b_{n-1}$ in this way:

- We add $n$ zeros at right of $b_{n-1}$;
- Add $n$;
- Add $j(n)$.

In formula
$$
b_0=0\\
b_n=b_{n-1}+\frac{1}{2^{L(n-1)}}\frac{1}{2^n}\frac{2n+j(n)}{2^{l(n)+1}}=b_{n-1}+\frac{2n+j(n)}{2^{L(n)}}
$$
the term $\frac{1}{2^{L(n-1)}}$ is used to left unchanged the preceding elements because $b_{n-1}$ decimal part is $L(n-1)$ long. In this way it's simple to show that
$$
f^{L(n)}(b_n)=0
$$
and
$$
f^{L(n-1)}(b_n)=\frac{1}{2^n}\frac{2n+j(n)}{2^{l(n)+1}}\leq\frac{1}{2^n}\frac{n}{2^{l(n)}}+\frac{1}{2^{n+l(n)+1}}
$$
(the terms $j(n)$ is used to neutralize the changing effect of $f$) and $b_n$ is a Cauchy sequence so we set $b_n\rightarrow a$.

Now if the term $n$ compares in a certain position in $a$ then also $2^kn$ where $k\in\mathbb N$ appears inside $a$ in a certain point of $a$ representation, because 
$$
\frac{2^kn}{2^{l(2^kn)}}=\frac{n}{2^{l(n)}}
$$

we have

$$
f^{L(2^kn-1)}(a)=\frac{1}{2^{2^kn}}\frac{2^kn}{2^{l(2^kn)}}+\dotsb\leq\frac{1}{2^{2^kn}}\frac{n}{2^{l(n)}}+\frac{1}{2^{2^kn+l(2^kn)+1}}
$$
and for evry $k$ such that $2^kn\geq u-1$
$$
f^{L(2^kn-1)+2^kn-u+1}(a)=\frac{1}{2^{u-1}}\frac{2^kn}{2^{l(2^kn)}}+\dotsb\leq\frac{1}{2^{u-1}}\frac{n}{2^{l(n)}}+\frac{1}{2^{u-1+l(2^kn)+1}}\\
0\leq \left\lvert f^{L(2^kn-1)+2^kn-u+1}(a)-\frac{1}{2^{u-1}}\frac{n}{2^{l(n)}}\right\rvert\leq \frac{1}{2^{u-1+l(2^kn)+1}}\rightarrow 0
$$
where $k\rightarrow +\infty$. Then the subsequence is
$$
i_k=L(2^kn-1)+2^kn-u+1\rightarrow +\infty
$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f(x)=2\min\{x,1-x\}$. If the binary expansion of $a$ is
$$a=0.b_1\ldots b_n0x_1x_2\ldots $$
(where not all $x_i$ are $=1$),
we conclude that the binary expansion of $a_{n+2}$ is $$a_{n+2}=0.x_1x_2\ldots$$
So in order to find a subsequence converging to $x$, we only need to make sure that longer and longer prefixes of the binary expansion of $x$ occur after a $0$ in the expansion of $a$ (where we use the expansion $0.1111\ldots$ for $x=1$). In order to achieve this for all possible $x\in[0,1]$, we just need to make sure that all possible bit patterns occur after a $0$. So let 
$$ a=0.0\color{red}00\color{red}10\color{red}{00}0\color{red}{01}0\color{red}{10}0\color{red}{11}0\color{red}{000}0\color{red}{001}0\color{red}{010}0\color{red}{011}0\color{red}{100}0\color{red}{101}0\color{red}{110}0\color{red}{111}0\color{red}{0000}0\color{red}{0001}\ldots$$

Comment: I get your idea and it's brilliant, but can you formalize this solution, since to me it seems very informal and I don't know how to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't (now) an answer, but an idea for a simpler solution.

Let $f^n=f\circ f\circ\dotsb\circ f$ $n$ times and $f^{-n}=f^{-1}\circ f^{-1}\circ\dotsb\circ f^{-1}$ $n$ times, the assertion is equivalent to find an $a\in ]0, 1[$ such that the set
$$
\mathcal{A}=\{f^n(a):n\in\mathbb N\}
$$
is dense in $]0, 1[$. Suppose that for every $a\in ]0, 1[$ exists an interval $I=]x, y[\subseteq \left]0, \frac{1}{2}\right[$ (or $\left]\frac{1}{2}, 1\right[$) with length $\frac{1}{2^k}$ such that
$$
I\cap\mathcal{A}=\emptyset
$$

Let $L=f^{-1}(I)$ observe that
$$
L=\left]\frac x2, \frac y2\right[\sqcup\left]1-\frac y2, 1-\frac x2\right[
$$
then $L$ is symmetric and $L\cap\mathcal A=\emptyset$ because $f^{-1}(\mathcal A)\supseteq\mathcal A$ and
$$
L_1=f^{-1}(L)=\frac{L}{2}\sqcup\left(1-\frac L2\right)
$$

In general

> For every $K\subseteq ]0, 1[$ let $K'=f^{-1}(K)$ then
>   $$
> K'=1-K'=\{1-k:k\in K'\}
> $$
>   Proof: For every $x\in ]0, 1[$ we have $f(x)=f(1-x)$ then
>   $$
> x\in K'\Leftrightarrow f(x)=f(1-x)\in K\Leftrightarrow 1-x\in K'
> $$

and define $L_n$ by recursion. Then we have
$$
L_n=f^{-1}(L_{n-1})=\frac{L_{n-1}}{2}\sqcup\left(1-\frac {L_{n-1}}2\right)\\
L_n=1-L_n\\
\lvert L_n\rvert = \lvert L\rvert =\frac{1}{2^k}\text{ the Lebesgue measure)}\\
L_n\cap\mathcal A=\emptyset
$$

Now we define this new function:
$$
g:x\in [0, 1]\rightarrow\begin{cases}
2x &\text{ if }2x\leq 1\\
2x -1 &\text{ if }2x > 1
\end{cases}
$$
Then it holds:

> If $K$ satisfy $K=1-K$ then
>   $$
> f^{-1}(K)=g^{-1}(K)
> $$
>   Proof: let $f(x)\in K$, if $2x\leq 1$ then $f(x)=g(x)$ otherwise $f(x)=2(1-x)$. Because $K$ is symmetric we have 
>   $$
> 1-f(x)=1-2(1-x)=1-2+2x=2x-1=g(x)\in K
> $$
>   and vice versa.

In particular
$$
f^{-1}(L_n)=g^{-1}(L_n)
$$
so we can work with $g$ instead of $f$, observe that $g$ works simply as a "left shift" of $x$ seen in binary representation then if the assertion isn't true for $f$ then it doesn't value neither for $g$, this function is more simpler than $f$ and we can work more simply on it, for example we can use a simplified version of the preceding solution because the "changing effect" doesn't appear when using $g$.